# How to add a separator character between each three numbers in an input field?

Tags: javascript, validation

How can I put a hyphen symbol (`-`) after the user types three numbers, then again after other three numbers. Like this:

> 719-646-636

It should be done automatically, in javascript.

Comment: So if user types in three numbers in input, automatically there will be dash/minus/hyphen symbol after it? I think you have to use some sorta event listener or something.

Comment: yeah, how to do that. please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good use case for the plugin [jquery-inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).

Take a look at the documentation, there are plenty of options.

You can get your desired behavior in a one-liner javascript (plus workable copy/paste and disabling non-numeric characters).

```js
$("input[name=my-numeric-value]").inputmask()
```

```css
input {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="my-numeric-value" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxx" data-inputmask="'mask': '999-999-999'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
const str = 'ababab';

const result = str.replace(/.{3}/g, '$&-');
```

Source : [https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-insert-character-every-n-characters#:~:text=To%20insert%20a%20character%20after,characters%20plus%20the%20provided%20replacement](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-insert-character-every-n-characters#:%7E:text=To%20insert%20a%20character%20after,characters%20plus%20the%20provided%20replacement).